# Visualforce: apex:form: inputs for parent and child with master-detail relationship?

Tags: visualforce

How to display this inputs in one form? I can not find any solution to implement this.

Comment: More explanation of the problem would be helpful.

Comment: @KeithC added, I just need to insert new parent and child items at one page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have edited the parent and child fields in the page, to join them together you take the ID that is available on the parent object after it has been inserted and set that (as the foreign key) on the child object before it is inserted:

```
public Parent__c parent {get; private set;}
public Child__c child {get; private set;}

// Constructor
public MyController() {
    parent = new Parent__c();
    child = new Child__c();
}

public PageReference save() {
    insert parent;
    child.Parent__c = parent.Id;
    insert child;
    return null;
}
```

To make the objects available in the Visualforce, initialise controller properties as shown then you can edit fields in the page like this:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!parent.FieldApiName__c}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!child.FieldApiName__c}"/>
```

**PS**

Relationship fields between objects (that end in `__r` in custom objects) are only normally populated when the objects are queried together. If there is just one parent and one child instead you can use the approach illustrated above.

Comment: Thank you for the apex, but how can I display inputs from this two objects? looks like `{!Parent__c.Child__c.field__c}` is not the correct code..

Comment: I get `Unknown property` for my child's input field at VF. Maybe you forgot to mention something?..

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich Nothing comes to mind - you'll have to debug. If this is all new to you, do some Googling to get more perspective on what should and shouldn't work.

Comment: as usual this is my carelessness - I typed `MyObject__c` instead of `parent`, thank you again for your help!

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich Glad you got it sorted.